# Printing HasMorePages not working c#

Tags: c#, printing

Alright so I have been looking around (on SO and Google) to see if a question could solve my error but apparently not, so here it goes:

I am trying to print something that will sometimes have more than one page and I am checking how many pages there is to print. After checking all this logic, I use the `HasMorePages` property to set if there is another page or not. This is my code:

```
int currentpage = 0;
int pagesleft = 0;
private void doc_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ev)
{
    ev.Graphics.Clear(Color.White);
    int numofpages = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)(numofwords / 29.0));
    numofpages = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)(numofwords / 29.0));
    currentpage = currentpage + 1;
    if(currentpage == 1)
    {
        pagesleft = numofpages;
    }
    if (numofwordsleft >= 29)
    {
        currentwords = 29;
    }
    else
    {
        currentwords = numofwordsleft;
    }
    Font f19 = new Font("Arial", (float)19);
    Font f9 = new Font("Arial", (float)9);            

    ev.Graphics.DrawString("Pages: "+numofpages.ToString()+"         Words: "+numofwords.ToString()+"     "+currentwords.ToString(), f19, Brushes.Red, 200, 300);
    ev.Graphics.DrawString("Words Left: "+numofwordsleft, f19, Brushes.Green, 200, 500);

    ev.Graphics.DrawString("Pages: "+numofpages.ToString()+"       Current Page: "+currentpage.ToString(), f19, Brushes.Blue, 200, 700);

    numofwordsleft = numofwordsleft - currentwords;
    pagesleft = pagesleft - 1;

    //currentpage++;
    //if (currentpage != numofpages && currentpage < numofpages && pagesleft > 0 && pagesleft != 0)
    if(currentpage < numofpages)
    {
        ev.HasMorePages = true;
    }
    else 
    {
        ev.HasMorePages = false;
    }
}
```

Now everything works like it should, but when I try to print more than one page it prints 2 pages instead. I did some debugging and found this:

[image]

So `HasMorePages` is equal to `false` so it should only print 1 page. I pressed continue debugging and it hit the breakpoint at the end again. Since I clear the page at the beginning I was only seeing the second page (in a `printpreview`) but the `printpreview` said that there was only 1 page and the only page that was being displayed was the second one.

Here is the `printpreview`:

[image]

For the blue text I am doing this:

```
ev.Graphics.DrawString("Pages: "+numofpages.ToString()+"    Current Page: "+currenpage.ToString(), ...);
```

And the print preview clearly says that it is on Page 1.

Sorry for the long post but I need help. Please post here if you can help me/point me in the right direction to solving this.

Thanks!

Edit: So when I try to print 2 pages, using:

```
int numofpages = Math.Ceiling(39.0 / 29.0);
```

It prints 3 pages but all on the same page as shown in `PrintPreview` unless that isn't working properly.

Comment: Use the BeginPrint event to reset the page counters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
    int currentpage = 0;
    int pagesleft = 0;
    int numofwordsleft = 0;
    int currentwords = 0;//For testing
    int numofwords = 120; // For testing
    private void doc_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ev)
    {
        ev.Graphics.Clear(Color.White);
        int numofpages = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)(numofwords / 29.0));
        numofpages = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)(numofwords / 29.0));
        currentpage = currentpage + 1;
        if (currentpage == 1)
        {
            pagesleft = numofpages;
        }
        if (numofwordsleft >= 29)
        {
            currentwords = 29;
        }
        else
        {
            currentwords = numofwordsleft;
        }
        Font f19 = new Font("Arial", (float)19);
        Font f9 = new Font("Arial", (float)9);

        ev.Graphics.DrawString("Pages: " + numofpages.ToString() + "         Words: " + numofwords.ToString() + "     " + currentwords.ToString(), f19, Brushes.Red, 200, 300);
        ev.Graphics.DrawString("Words Left: " + numofwordsleft, f19, Brushes.Green, 200, 500);

        ev.Graphics.DrawString("Pages: " + numofpages.ToString() + "       Current Page: " + currentpage.ToString(), f19, Brushes.Blue, 200, 700);

        numofwordsleft = numofwordsleft - currentwords;
        pagesleft = pagesleft - 1;

        //currentpage++;
        //if (currentpage != numofpages && currentpage < numofpages && pagesleft > 0 && pagesleft != 0)
        if (currentpage < numofpages)
        {
            ev.HasMorePages = true;
        }
        else
        {
            ev.HasMorePages = false;
        }
    }
```

hope this helps.
This is the preview i am getting after changing  number of words.
[image: Print Preview Screen Shot]

Comment: can you paste here full line of Graphics.DrawString please i need to check with the code.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this soon if my new method doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try with the following:

```
int currentpage = 0;
private void doc_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ev)
{
    ev.Graphics.Clear(Color.White);
    int numofpages = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)(numofwords / 29.0));
    currentpage++;
    // Print some graphics onto ev.Graphics
    ev.HasMorePages = (currentpage < numofpages)
}
```

Do not forget to include currentpage=0; before starting a new print!

UPDATE:

Your print starts by a button click or a menuitem click or whatever. Assuming that you use a button, what is expected (as minimum) is something like this:

```
private void cmdStartPrint_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    currentpage = 0;
    PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
    pd.PrintPage  += new PrintPageEventHandler(this.doc_PrintPage);
    pd.Print();
}
```

And a tip: dispose what is disposable (including pd)

Comment: It works for me. Probably you do more than the presented code in your question that may change the expected behavior or it. It will be more helpful to show us your full code.

Comment: I will be able to post the code as soon as I get back in 20 minutes.

Comment: I have edited the original code and added all of the code that does not include the printing graphics (its pretty big).

Comment: The code you added at the bottom is very identical to what I have, I just have `currentpage = 0` somewhere else.

Comment: If this "somewhere else" is not firing before you start a new print then this is the problem. Sorry, but it's extremely difficult to come up with a solution while the "image" of the problem is not so clear.

Comment: The somewhere else is in the class `Form1`. I added `currentpage = 0` to the `buttonclick` and will try it now. I will try to clear the post up so you can understand it clearly, Thanks.

Comment: I understand the post, but I don't have/see the full source. So if the problem is somewhere else, then the only thing I can do is guessing with no guarantee for accuracy/matching.

Comment: Tonight I will upload it to pastebin and link it here.

Answer (score -1):

Fix pagination problem when printing in C# using HasMorePages.
Explanation about this code: You can add many rows or read from the database to see the result of pagination during printing, for example, I added only two rows to the table manually, which is not paginated because the number of rows is small. Add many rows manually or insert information from the database into the grid view. This is an example:

```
int currentPage = 1;
int rowsPerPage = 36; //Number of rows per page
int rowIndex = 0;

void pdoc_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        int x = 5, y = 5; //Drawing start position
        int rowMargin = 0; //Spacing between lines

        dgvHesaab.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;
        dgvHesaab.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;

        dgvHesaab.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
        dgvHesaab.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.EnableResizing; //Text with more lines in a row.
        dgvHesaab.ColumnHeadersHeight = 40; //40=row height. Text with more lines in a row.

        dgvHesaab.RightToLeft = RightToLeft.Yes;

        int rowCount = dgvHesaab.Rows.Count; //Get the number of rows
        int pageCount = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling(Convert.ToDouble(rowCount) / Convert.ToDouble(rowsPerPage)));

        //Set header content of columns
        for (int j = this.dgvHesaab.Columns.Count - 1; j >= 0; j--)
        {
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(x, y, 132, dgvHesaab.Rows[0].Height); //132 = width in row
            StringFormat sf = new StringFormat();
            sf.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
            sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.LightGray, rect);
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, rect);
            if (this.dgvHesaab.Columns[j].HeaderText != null)
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawString(this.dgvHesaab.Columns[j].HeaderText, SystemFonts.DefaultFont, Brushes.Black, rect, sf);
            }
            x += rect.Width;
        }

        x = 5;
        y += dgvHesaab.Rows[0].Height + rowMargin;
        //Set the content of the lines
        while (rowIndex < dgvHesaab.Rows.Count)
        {
            DataGridViewRow row = dgvHesaab.Rows[rowIndex];
            if (row.Cells[0].Value != null)
            {
                for (int j = this.dgvHesaab.Columns.Count - 1; j >= 0; j--)
                {
                    DataGridViewCell cell = row.Cells[j];
                    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(x, y, 132, dgvHesaab.Rows[0].Height); //132 = width in row
                    StringFormat sf = new StringFormat();
                    sf.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
                    sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
                    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, rect);
                    if (cell.Value != null)
                    {
                        e.Graphics.DrawString(cell.Value.ToString(), new Font("Tahoma", 8, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, rect, sf);
                    }
                    x += rect.Width;
                }
                x = 5;
                y += dgvHesaab.Rows[0].Height + rowMargin;
            }
            rowIndex++;

            //Print a new page if necessary
            if (rowIndex % rowsPerPage == 0 || rowIndex == dgvHesaab.Rows.Count)
            {
                e.HasMorePages = (currentPage < pageCount);
                currentPage++;
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

    }
}

   
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        //Begin , Adding a row to the gridView(dgvHesaab) 
        ///<summary>
        ///For example, the name of our Grid View is dgvHesaab
        ///Retrieving data from a database or manually inserting data for a row. 
        ///</summary>

        //add row 1
        dgvHesaab.Rows.Add(new object[]
        {
            "Row 1 : Item 1",
            "Row 1 : Item 2",
            "Row 1 : Item 3",
            "Row 1 : Item 4",
            "Row 1 : Item 5",
            "Row 1 : Item 6",
        });

        //add row 2
        dgvHesaab.Rows.Add(new object[]
        {
            "Row 2 : Item 1",
            "Row 2 : Item 2",
            "Row 2 : Item 3",
            "Row 2 : Item 4",
            "Row 2 : Item 5",
            "Row 2 : Item 6",
        });
        //End , Adding a row to the gridView(dgvHesaab)  

        dgvHesaab.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;
        dgvHesaab.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;

        dgvHesaab.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
        dgvHesaab.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.EnableResizing; //Text with more lines in a row.
        dgvHesaab.ColumnHeadersHeight = 40; //40=row height. Text with more lines in a row.

        dgvHesaab.RightToLeft = RightToLeft.Yes;

        //Begin Print
        PrintDialog pDialog = new PrintDialog();
        pDialog.AllowCurrentPage = false;
        pDialog.AllowPrintToFile = false;
        pDialog.AllowSelection = false;
        pDialog.AllowSomePages = false;
        pDialog.PrintToFile = false;
        pDialog.ShowHelp = false;
        pDialog.ShowNetwork = false;
        if (pDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument pdoc = new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument();
            pdoc.PrintPage += new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventHandler(pdoc_PrintPage);
            pdoc.DocumentName = "Print Title";
            pdoc.PrinterSettings = pDialog.PrinterSettings;
            pdoc.DefaultPageSettings = pDialog.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings;
            pdoc.DefaultPageSettings.Margins = new System.Drawing.Printing.Margins(100, 100, 100, 100);
            pdoc.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = new System.Drawing.Printing.PaperSize("A4", 827, 1169);
            pdoc.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = false; //Landscape
            //pdoc.PrinterSettings.Copies = 3;
            PrintPreviewDialog printPreviewDialog1 = new PrintPreviewDialog();
            printPreviewDialog1.Document = pdoc;
            pdoc.Print(); //No preview  
            //printPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog(); //printPreview
        }
        //End Print
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

    }
}
```