# Print List<> to PrintDocument - display first 37 items, then the next 37 and so on

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, printing

Objective: Print out records that are read into my application and stored in Lists<> like this http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/733680/Printing-and-Previewing-multiple-pages-in-Csharp and https://stackoverflow.com/a/11067893/2952390. More so I want to print out the first 37 records (if there is that much) on the first page, then the next 37 on the second page and so on. The information is displayed into a basic table with many columns in my `PrintDocument`. I could have up to 22500 records! For example, if I have 104 records I would need 3 pages and the general layout should be like the following:

[image]

The following code displays all **records on all pages but overlapping**. I can see that the code has managed to divide the records into displaying 37 at a time in the correct position, but the page doesn't clear so it just overlaps. Also the `if` statement may be incorrect as I'm not sure if it will display only 74 records or the whole 104 records.

```
int currentpage = 0;
int pagesleft = 0;
readonly PrintDocument docccc = new PrintDocument();
readonly PrintPreviewDialog printpreviewdialog = new PrintPreviewDialog();

    private void Summary_Preview(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        printpreviewdialog.Document = docccc;
        docccc.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;
        docccc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(Summary_English);
        printpreviewdialog.ShowDialog();
    }

    private void Summary_Print(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        docccc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(Summary_English);
        printDialog1.Document = docccc;
        docccc.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;
        printDialog1.ShowDialog();

        if (printDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            docccc.Print();
        }
    }

private void Summary_English(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    // Title
    // Extra text
    // Table headers

    int rec_count = Details.rec_num.Count; // Counts the total records from file
    int pageCount = (rec_count + 37 - 1) / 37; // Calculates how many pages there should be
    currentpage = currentpage + 1;

    if (currentpage == 1)
    {
        pagesleft = pageCount;
    }

    e.Graphics.DrawString(currentpage.ToString() + " | " + pageCount.ToString(), new Font("Courier New", 8, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Gray,
         new System.Drawing.Rectangle(22, 780, 1125, 15), Align_Centre);

    int rec = 1; // Initiate record to read
    int y = 257; // Initiate text position

    for (; rec < rec_count; rec++)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawString(Details.rec_num[rec - 1] + "\n", ar_7_reg, Brushes.Black, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(22, y, 32, 485));
        e.Graphics.DrawString(Details.datetime[rec] + "\n", ar_7_reg, Brushes.Black, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(54, y, 96, 485));
        e.Graphics.DrawString(Details.volt[rec] + "V\n", ar_7_reg, Brushes.Black, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(240, y, 40, 485));
        e.Graphics.DrawString(Details.expectedAtime[rec] + " S\n", ar_7_reg, Brushes.Black, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(394, y, 68, 485));
        e.Graphics.DrawString(Details.actualtime1[rec] + " S\n", ar_7_reg, Brushes.Black, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(462, y, 102, 485));
        e.Graphics.DrawString(Details.expectedBtime[rec] + " S\n", ar_7_reg, Brushes.Black, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(564, y, 69, 485));
        e.Graphics.DrawString(Details.actualtime2[rec] + " S\n", ar_7_reg, Brushes.Black, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(633, y, 102, 485));
        e.Graphics.DrawString(Details.error[rec] + "\n", ar_7_reg, Brushes.Black, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(735, y, 92, 485));

        y += 13; // Increment line gap between each rec

        if (rec % 37 == 0)
        {
            y = 257;
        }

        if (currentpage < pageCount)
        { 
            e.HasMorePages = true;              
        }
        else
        {
            e.HasMorePages = false;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: The most important piece of code is missing in your question.  Your BeginPrint event handler.  That's where you open the file (?) and initialize your record or page counter.   Then the PrintPage event handler simply reads a record from the file and prints it.  Up to 37 times.  If it gets to 37 without encountering end-of-file then you need to set HasMorePages to true.

Comment: every time when loop being executed. it will be started from the first item. you should use also `skip` in your item list.

Comment: @HansPassant That makes sense, sounds similar to your preview answer in http://stackoverflow.com/a/13777923/2952390. Is it still possible to print the list in a foreach loop? This is because sometimes I could have records like 1,2,3,8,9,11... I don't want 1,2,3,4,5,6 to be displayed, or am I getting confused :/?

Comment: *similar to your previous

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed it!!! YAY! So happy. For people who were in my position and struggling:

```
int currentpage = 0;
int pagesleft = 0;
int rec = 0;

private void Summary_English(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    rec = rec += 1;

    // Title
    // Extra text
    // Table headers

    int rec_count = Details.rec_num.Count; // Counts the total records from file
    int pageCount = (rec_count + 37 - 1) / 37; // Calculates how many pages there should be
    int y = 257;
    currentpage = currentpage + 1;

    if (currentpage == 1)
    {
        pagesleft = pageCount - 1;
    }

    for (; rec < rec_count; rec++)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawString(Details.rec_num[rec - 1] + "\n", ar_7_reg, Brushes.Black, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(22, y, 32, 485));
        e.Graphics.DrawString(Details.datetime[rec] + "\n", ar_7_reg, Brushes.Black, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(54, y, 96, 485));
        e.Graphics.DrawString(Details.volt[rec] + "V\n", ar_7_reg, Brushes.Black, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(240, y, 40, 485));
        e.Graphics.DrawString(Details.expectedAtime[rec] + " S\n", ar_7_reg, Brushes.Black, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(394, y, 68, 485));
        e.Graphics.DrawString(Details.actualtime1[rec] + " S\n", ar_7_reg, Brushes.Black, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(462, y, 102, 485));
        e.Graphics.DrawString(Details.expectedBtime[rec] + " S\n", ar_7_reg, Brushes.Black, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(564, y, 69, 485));
        e.Graphics.DrawString(Details.actualtime2[rec] + " S\n", ar_7_reg, Brushes.Black, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(633, y, 102, 485));
        e.Graphics.DrawString(Details.error[rec] + "\n", ar_7_reg, Brushes.Black, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(735, y, 92, 485));

        y += 13;

        if (rec % 37 == 0)
        {
            y = 257;
            break;
        }
    }

    e.HasMorePages = currentpage < pageCount;
}
```

There wasn't as much code as I first anticipated!